# An issue with Asymmetric algorithm usage

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to use the asymmetric encryption to encrypt the message at client side using public key  and decrypt at server side with private key.

After decrypting the messages it is not matching with the plattext. Could you please help me on this?

Below is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

public class GenerateKeys {

    public static void saveToFile(String fileName, BigInteger mod,
            BigInteger exp) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
        try {
            oout.writeObject(mod);
            oout.writeObject(exp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected error", e);
        } finally {
            oout.close();
        }
    }

    public static void rsaKeyGeneration() {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
        try {
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
        System.out.println("Algo is :" + publicKey.getAlgorithm());

        KeyFactory fact = null;
        try {
            fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RSAPublicKeySpec pub = null;
        try {
            pub = fact.getKeySpec(publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = null;
        try {
            priv = fact.getKeySpec(privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            saveToFile("C:/public1.key", pub.getModulus(),
                    pub.getPublicExponent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            saveToFile("C:/private1.key", priv.getModulus(),
                    priv.getPrivateExponent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    PublicKey readKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(keyFileName);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                in));

        try {
            BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
            return pubKey;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
        } finally {
            oin.close();
        }
    }

    public byte[] rsaEncrypt(byte[] data) {
        PublicKey pubKey = null;
        try {
            pubKey = readKeyFromFile("C:/public1.key");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] cipherData = null;
        try {
            cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out
                .println("encrypted card number is :" + cipherData.toString());
        return cipherData;
    }

    PrivateKey readPriKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(keyFileName);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                in));

        try {
            BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(m, e);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey pKey = fact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
            return pKey;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
        } finally {
            oin.close();
        }
    }

    public byte[] rsaDecrypt(byte[] sampleText) {
        PrivateKey priKey = null;
        try {
            priKey = readPriKeyFromFile("C:/private1.key");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priKey);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] cipherData = null;
        try {
            cipherData = cipher.doFinal(sampleText);
            // cipherData = cipher.
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cipherData;
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        System.out
                .println("++++++++++++++++++++ Program to create the Keys+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        rsaKeyGeneration();
        String sText = "HRB";
        System.out.println("Plain Text Card Number :" + sText);
        GenerateKeys keys = new GenerateKeys();
        byte[] encryptedCardNo = keys.rsaEncrypt(sText.getBytes());
        byte[] decryptedCardNo = keys.rsaDecrypt(encryptedCardNo);
        System.out.println("Decrypted card number is :"
                + decryptedCardNo.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: you got some tips down here, please mark it as closed.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal because you are using the `toString()` method which returns an awful representation. So you should use an hexadecimal representation to display both encrypted and decrypted text. Here's a function that do the work :

```
public String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bArray){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    for(byte b : bArray) {
      buffer.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
      buffer.append(" ");
    }

    return buffer.toString();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the String.getBytes(Charset): byte[] and new String(byte[], Charset): String methods instead of toString(). toString() will just give you the reference to the byte array. As charset, use Charset.forName("UTF-8") which is always supported by any Java compatible platform (and Apache Harmony, in all likelyhood).

```
private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

...

```
System.out.println(new String("Hi there!".getBytes(UTF8), UTF8));
```

Comment: However in no case should you attempt to construct a String instance from the byte array that results from encryption. Every Charset supports only a subset of all possible codes, but cipher output can be completely arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for the addition GregS. This was about displaying the decrypted data, so I did not mention it.